# Android (v12 > ) restarts the app after enabling/disabling notifications from settings

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I am developing an app which supports push notifications.
App is automatically restarting after disabling notifications from device settings.

this happens for android v > 12.

Is this required by system or how can I solve it?

Comment: It might be that this is considered a configuration change or permission change now. Or, it might be akin to the wallpaper situation that [I wrote about here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/10/31/android-12-wallpaper-changes-recreate-activities.html).